# How to use Split() function inside an Expression in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, string, expressions

I would like to use Split function inside my expression in salesforce lightning. 
I'm passing a map from my class and receiving the same in js controller and then converting it to List attribute for component utilization.

My map is getting retured as this sample,

```
Map<String,String>
myMap -> key = "textSplit0_textSplit1" , value = "someString"
```

In JS Controller, I'm converting the map as list like this,

```
var output = response.getReturnValue();
var someMap = [];
if(output){
    for( var key in output ){
        someMap.push({key:key, value:output[key]});
    }
component.set("v.allCustomLinksMap",someMap);
}
```

in my component, I have a List attribute and i want to iterate over my map for the above.
I have code like this, and am facing a syntax error.

Here, `{!cus.key}` works fine but I would like to get myMap's Key splitted at '_' and returned as expected below.

```
<aura:attribute name="allCustomLinksMap" type="List"/>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.allCustomLinksMap}" var="cus" indexVar="key">

    <h3 class="slds-truncate" title="{!cus.key}">{!(cus.key.split('_'){0})}</h3>

    <div class="slds-tile__detail slds-text-body_small">
    <dl class="slds-list--horizontal slds-wrap">
        <a href="{!cus.value}">{!(cus.key.split('_'){1})}</a>
    </dl>                                   

</div>

</aura:iteration>
```

is there a way to achieve this ? TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only methods you can use in expressions are found in the [Expressions Function Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm), and for the most part, they appear more or less like how formula fields operate (in other words, the correct expression would look something like `{!split(cus.key,'_')[1]}`). However, split isn't a supported function. You would necessarily need to process that data in your controller.

---

```
    someMap.push({key:key, key0: key.split('_')[0], key1:key.split('_')[1], value:output[key]});
```

---

```
<h3 class="slds-truncate" title="{!cus.key}">{!cus.key0}</h3>
```

---

```
    <a href="{!cus.value}">{!cus.key1}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the other solution. split() did not work on the expression , I used the other part of your code.

Comment: @AjaySFDC Yes, as I mentioned, "split" isn't a supported expression. Any type of manipulation of data you need to do is best done in the controller, when possible